# Innertopmargin conflict with mdframed and amsthm

Tags: formatting

I use the [mdframed](https://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed?lang=en) package to highlight environments in my latex document. However, there seems to be a bug when using mdframed together with amsthm. In this case the argument *innertopmargin* seems to be ignored (the blue line ends above the *E* and not at the same height.)

Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newmdtheoremenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  innermargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  linewidth=1.5pt,
  linecolor=blue,
]{example}[section]{Example}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the `amsthm` documentation

> Space above and below: [...] for amsthm used as a separate package, it is the local value of \topsep.

So you can compensate this additional space by setting `innertopmargin` to `-\topsep`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\newmdtheoremenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  innermargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innertopmargin=-\topsep,
  linewidth=1.5pt,
  linecolor=blue,
]{example}[section]{Example}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could also change the value of `\topsep` (caveat: this will also influence all other things that use `\topsep`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}

\newmdtheoremenv[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  innermargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  linewidth=1.5pt,
  linecolor=blue,
]{example}[section]{Example}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{example}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]